# IIS server won't load web application

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a web application in my iis and i locate in :

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blabla\Test\Web.aspx
```

And i have a domain , that i browse to the web page with this:

```
www.mydomain.com/Test/web.aspx
```

And i want to be able to connect the page without the domain too:

```
http://123.123.8.78/blabla/Test/Web.aspx
```

When i browse with the domain i get the page but when i try with the IP address i get:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'App.Web'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Web.aspx.cs" Inherits="App.Web" %>


Source File: /blabla/test/web.aspx    Line: 1
```

Any idea why i can't get the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

blabla is the directory that the website is pointed at, which is why /Test/web.aspx works.  You need to install a virtual directory to point at blabla on your default web site in order for the second URL request to work.  Just specifying the site name in the URL does not work.

The default web site is picking up the directory /blabla/Test/Web.aspx but the bin directory that it is using for dynamic compilation is the default web site's home directory, not the www.mydomain.com site.

Comment: It is some thing that i need to do in the IIS server or in the web code?

Comment: On the server.  Add a virtual directory to the default web site and you are set.